# Macbook started to consume battery more quickly

Tags: macbook-pro, power, battery

This seemed to happen after I did several things at once (all of which I have since reversed in trying to track this down):

1. installed a (Crucial M4) SSD drive (replacing my old SATA 5400 RPM drive),
2. upgraded from 2GB RAM to 4GB, and
3. upgraded to Mountain Lion (from Snow Leopard)

For weeks I've been trying to track down what the problem could be.  I've read all sorts of things about Mountain Lion using more power and various conflicting things on the Crucial forums about whether or not their SSDs consume more or less power (SSDs are generally advertised as being less power-hungry but there are a few conflicting reports!).

Anyway, I'm now back to my old SATA drive, my original 2 GB RAM and a completely clean install of Snow Leopard.  But I still have a reduced battery life and I can't figure out why.

Where I'm at now is that the milliAmps consumed by my MacBook when it is pretty much completely idle (i.e. 1-3% CPU usage in Activity Monitor, All Processes) it is consuming about

925 mA (according to System Profiler)

It fluctuates, but often goes up above 1400 mA and never lower than 750 mA.  I never paid attention to this value before but I know two things:

1. I used to get > 6 hours battery life in normal usage (emails, browsing) and now I get < 4.
2. My friend's MacBook idles at around 450 mA.

My fan speed is 1800rpm during this normal usage.

Any ideas how I can solve this?  Is there perhaps anything else I can reset?  It feels like a hardware issue.

Alternatively, is there a way to see the number of mA being drawn by the various components of my MacBook?

Comment: +1 For all the work you've done trying to get this figured out already. I hope you will receive some help on this.

Comment: Interesting. My Macbook (late '08) is using ~ 1600 mA when I just checked. Course, my battery lasts only about an hour with a cycle count of 483, and health of 80%.

Comment: Have you tried to reset the SMC (or SMU, PMU, depending how old your Mac is)? I would give it a try. Maybe when you changed the hardware there have been some changes which haven't been redone. http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964?viewlocale=en_EN&locale=en_EN

Comment: Yes, I've tried that but no discernable difference.

Comment: Perhaps in the process of disassembling/reassembling the MacBook, something was not re-aligned correctly, or something invisibly broke, and current is being drained from the battery as a result. Given the tight tolerances inside one of these magical devices, I would guess this is what happened.

Comment: Mine idles at -1017mA. That's not supposed to be negative, right? ;) A software bug, I guess. Anyway, IconDaemon, that's not as likely as it may sound. Drainage to the point where it would cut the battery life that seriously would cause either lots of static or heating, depending on what was draining. Ben would've definitely noticed either symptom. Plus, installing RAM and an SSD is not that deep into the innards of a Macbook.

Comment: How many cycles does the battery have? Is the battery health reported as ok? (also in system profiler)

Comment: Might sound trivial, but have you turned off Bluetooth? Also display brightness can make a noticeable difference.

Comment: My brightness is way down low (less than 20% along the slider) and I'm currently idling at -1008mA (mine shows as negative BTW - perhaps not a bug Joost, cause it's positive when plugged into the charger).  And my Bluetooth is permanently off.

Comment: On the subject of current being drained as a result of misalignment or an internal breakage, the former had crossed my mind.  I didn't go deep to replace RAM and SSD, as Joost says, and I've been back in a few times to ensure everything is seated really tightly.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at top -u to see if there are active processes that should not be there.

I would look at the system profile: Apple => About This Mac => More Info... => System Report => Power and see what it says about the battery... In particular the Condition and Cycle Count.

To compare two Macs, be sure the brightness is the same and both are spinning down their disks.